# AngularJS inside AJAX page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ajax

I have a shell file called ajaxshell.html. This has an AngularJS app that loads another page called entrypage.html and renders that as HTML using $sce.

In entrypage.html I would like to use Angular for validation purposes - checking that certain fields have been edited, for example. However, entrypage.html simply cannot seem to find Angular(tested by using a simple ng-repeat) no matter which of the 2 pages I include it in.

How can I access Angular from within entrypage.html?

Comment: Yes, although currently I have removed the ng-app and ng-controller for testing,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have entrypage.html brought in as the template for a directive, rather than a welded-in piece of HTML. If you need the URL to be dynamic, you can assign a function to `templateUrl` when declaring a directive, and it can put together the URL on-the-fly for you. Angular will then consider the page to be a valid component of itself.

Comment: I'm planning to have multiple pages for this one controller though. Does your solution work in that case? Is this bad design?

Comment: Could you clarify? What controller are you referring to? My first thought is that there's nothing wrong with it, but I'd need more details to try to really answer.

Comment: The controller in ajaxshell.html is planned to be the controller for all of the pages that I am going to insert into it. I'm going to use it do the routing and such as well.

Comment: You can do that, though you may want to consider having different controllers that use the _same function_. Remember, the actual controller function is just a function variable that you're passing as a parameter to Angular's `.controller()` function. You can store that variable and reuse it elsewhere. This allows you to have the same logic while allowing you to tweak the entry conditions (e.g. template, resolves, etc.). I don't know how `$scope` handles being in a controller nested in itself, but based on playing with [this](http://codepen.io/RevillWeb/pen/WbQpaV), it actually seems fine.

Comment: As far as having a single controller that you provide to different components (routes, directives, etc), where only one uses it at a time, that is perfectly legal, and part of the intended reusability in Angular.

Comment: Alright, great! I'm working through what you've suggested now and assuming it functions then you'll get the nice green checkmark.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106756/discussion-between-warsame-and-harris-weinstein).

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to implement templating or follow online guides on how to do it. Could you link a guide that would be useful for doing it?

Comment: See my comment in chat.